# dots, commas etc get converted into a special symbol "?" in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i'm using a database to fetch datas. there are almost 750 questions in database.some questions contain special character's like ",....,' etc. but while fetch the data and print it in a textview it get converted into "?". is there any way to remove these kind of symbols and print it in original format.

[image]

I used the below code for fetching and displaying in textview.

```
    qsql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from mydata where col_1 = '365'"];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [qsql UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == (SQLITE_ROW))
    { 

        char *field0 = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        char *field1 = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
        NSString *t1 = nil;
        if(field0!=NULL){
          t1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:field0];
            //NSString *t1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:field0 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"%@jujuj" ,t1);
        }
        NSString *t2 = nil;
        if(field1!=NULL){
            t2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:field1];
             NSLog(@"%@jhjhh" ,t2);
        }


        NSString *string=t1;
        NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@",."];
      string = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        NSLog(@"%@jhgkjghkjg",string);
        //NSLog(@"%@ %@",Q_NO, Q_NO1);
        tv.text=t1;
        tv1.text=t2;



        [t1 release];
        [t2 release];
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSCharacterSet to remove that special Character from you string

```
NSString *string = @"ram,...";
    NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@",."];
    string = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);
```

Comment: narayana,is there any way to print in the correct manner in text view.also i have no direct text like @"ram.." in string.im fetching it from database,so how can i modify my code.please help me

Comment: you Can write my code at the time of retrieving  data from database

Comment: i edited my answer with your code.but still (?) it is comin.can you please tell me where im goin wrong. –

Comment: NSLog(@"%@jujuj" ,t1);
 in console what printing above statement

Comment: NSLog(@"%@jujuj" ,t1); is printing the question in NSLog,but there also that symbol is coming..

Comment: Narayana,i think that while entering into database at that time itself we have to remove that symbol?

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
    const char *sqlStatement = Select * from mydata where col_1 = '365'"; 
sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement; 


if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {

        while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {

            nsstring *t1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
```

Comment: when i use your code some warning is coming in first statment "incompatible pointer types initializing 'const c.."

Comment: const char *sqlStatement = @"Select * from mydata where col_1 = '365'"; in this line